# my godot label text is highlighted yellow and text is red but i didnt do this

Tags: text, godot, godot4, visual-glitch

I have been unable to fix it as the text is glitching out. I am on a Chromebook currently and I had this issue after accidentally powering off. then when i powered back on, it was glitching out. I have tried going into editor setting and fixing it that way but no prevail. I do not have any clue on to what is going on as some of the text is not broken and some on a instantiated scene is just black and blocky.

Comment: No idea. A picture might give some clue.